# Can I make a utility method which takes an arbitrary expression as a parameter and calls it?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

The exact reasons I might want to do this are a bit hard to go into without posting loads of code, but here's an example of one scenario:

```
try
{
    x.Method(123,"test");
    Assert.Fail("No exception thrown");
}
catch (ApplicationException e)
{
    StringAssert.StartsWith(e.Message, "Oh no!");
}
```

I'd like to refactor this to something like... (pseudo-code)

```
TestExceptionMessage({x.Method(123,"test")},"Oh no!");

void TestExceptionMessage(func,string message)
{
    try
    {
        func();
        Assert.Fail("No exception thrown");
    }
    catch (ApplicationException e)
    {
        StringAssert.StartsWith(e.Message, message);
    }
}
```

I know C# is pretty flexible with lambdas and so on, but is this pushing it too far or is it reasonable straightforward?

Comment: FYI, [`List.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z\(v=vs.110\).aspx) is one example of something that takes such a parameter (but with one more parameter in the lambda). You can use it for reference.

Comment: You can do it. Look at Func<> or Action<> which are a kind of delegate

Comment: In your specific case you may want to use `Assert.Throws<ApplicationException>(() => foo).WithMessage("bob")` assuming that's nunit.

Comment: @RJFalconer I'm using MSTest which doesn't support this AFAIK but it's a fair comment - I got the issue from testing but then was curious in the general case.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I got pretty frustrated with the Microsoft unit test framework some time ago and switched to NUnit. It's much easier to use IMO, it's since become standard practice at my company. But if you're sticking with MSTest, you might find [this](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html) helpful.

Comment: Don't use something like that in production code, especially since it's hiding an exception. For test code, it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and it's pretty straight forward. You can pass a [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate (or really any delegate type) into a method and call it:

```
void TestExceptionMessage(Action action, string message)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        Assert.Fail("No exception thrown");
    }
    catch (ApplicationException e)
    {
        StringAssert.StartsWith(e.Message, message);
    }
}
```

That delegate can be a reference to a method or it could be a lambda expression like this:

```
var x = new MyClass();
TestExceptionMessage(() => x.Method(123, "test"),"Oh no!");
```

However, if you really want to know the *expression* being used (e.g. if you want to be able to tell what method is being called) you need to use an [`Expression<Action>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
void TestExceptionMessage(Expression<Action> expression, string message)
{
    try
    {
        var methodName = (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression)?.Method.Name;
        if (methodName != null) 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine($"Calling {methodName}");
        }
        expression.Compile().Invoke();
        Assert.Fail("No exception thrown");
    }
    catch (ApplicationException e)
    {
        StringAssert.StartsWith(e.Message, message);
    }
}
```

And thanks to a little compiler magic, you can call with the same lambda syntax:

```
var x = new MyClass();
TestExceptionMessage(() => x.Method(123, "test"),"Oh no!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the more 'advanced' version, fascinating